# Secure FTP client for Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, ftp, sftp, ftps, windows-explorer

I have a small business website that once in awhile I need to upload files to. Before recently I've been keeping an `ftp` login string in my password manager, that looked as such:

```
ftp://username:password@serverN.hostingcompany.com:port
```

I would then copy and paste it into the address bar of the Windows Explorer:

[image]

that will open up files that are hosted on the web server. I can then upload, rename & delete files, etc.

So then someone told me that sending my credentials via plain `ftp` protocol is very unsafe and suggested using `ftps` instead. Unfortunately, if I replace the protocol with `ftps` in the string above, Windows doesn't seem to know how to handle it.

How do you guys upload files to the web server in a secure way? Preferably something that works with Windows (and namely Windows Explorer)?

PS. I did my research and someone recommended using [Swish](http://www.swish-sftp.org/). I tried, but the thing is so buggy that it would literally crash my Windows Explorer that would require later reboot just to get my Windows back.

Comment: You need to have a ftps _server_ first. :)

Comment: @RyanRies: I'm using a shared web hosting service that does support secure ftp.

Comment: Use any file copying software that supports SFTP.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I have to answer my own question. I tried some products and found that [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) (in `Explorer` GUI setting) matches the most to the Windows Explorer behavior. (And it supports secure `ftp` protocol.)

Another benefit is that it comes as a portable executable. No need to have an MSI installer "vomit" files all over your system drive.

It also looks to be an open source (you can [download a source code](https://winscp.net/download/WinSCP-5.9.6-Source.zip).)